# How to read major, minor from android beacon

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I use some sticknfind beacons with android (sticknfind android SDK). How do I get the major and minor value from a beacon within my sourcecode? I have used the app: StickNFind Beacon Maker and I have specified the values.

`Major: 0001`   `Minor: 0002`

in order to get the uuid: `dev.getBtDevice().getAddress()`

is there no `dev.getBtDevice().getMinor()`  or `getMajor()`?

Answer (score 5):

```
public String getMajor() {
    major = String.valueOf( (mScanRecord[25] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (mScanRecord[26] & 0xff));
    return major;
}

public String getMinor() {
    minor =     String.valueOf( (mScanRecord[27] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (mScanRecord[28] & 0xff));
    return minor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what SDK you are using when you call `getBtDevice().getAddress()`, but I suspect that will return you the Bluetooth MAC address and not the ProximityUUID you are seeking.  This is likely why there us no equivalent method to get major and minor.

Fortunately, there is an easier way if your beacons are already transmitting.  Just install the [iBeacon Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate) app and use it to read your identifiers over the air.

If you want to do this programmatically, check out the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/) on which the app is based.

Comment: I am using the sticknfind android skd, and yes i get the mac address.

Comment: Did anyone try changing UUID of sticknfind beacons ??Is that working ??

Answer (score 1):

I use the [RadiusNetwork's iBeacon library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/download.html) ([Android library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/)):

As simple as:

```
iBeacon.getProximityUuid()
iBeacon.getMajor()
iBeacon.getMinor()
```

Comment: Can  please share RadiusNetwork's iBeacon library ?They removed it from Github :(

Comment: As told in there README.md file, they now got a v2 in progress https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library. It's not my work, so try to contact them if you want the v1.

Answer (score 0):

Using alt beacon library 2.3.5, add this to you app module in your Build.gradle file:

```
compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.3.5'
```

Then, you can get the major and minor from the methods `getId2()` and `getId3()` of the Beacon class respectively.